# Dot Net Nuke Installation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dotnetnuke

I am new to Dot Net Nuke. I downloaded and tried to install it onto Windows Server 2008. It installs to the point where it starts running scripts for the database. I choose SQL Server 2005/2008 as the database and put in the correct Database name and connection string with the correct credentials as well. It however fails after running a few scripts and says "undefined...FAILURE NULL NULL". I fail to understand this error. Any help guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: show us the output from the database scripts please

Answer (score 0):

What database are you actually using? 2005/2008 express or full version?

Is the DB server on the same server as the website? If not you may have issues with IP access to a remote DB.

Can you share your DB connection settings from your web.config (hide credentials if required) - Remember the connection string is required twice (once in ConnectionStrings and once in AppSettings).